# Setting the call order of mutliple asyncio.Protocol.data_received

Tags: python-asyncio

When using asyncio for receiving multiple files over a TCP socket I struggle with the call order of received_data. When sending 3 data streams at once my output is the following:

```
DEBUG connection_made ('127.0.0.1', 33972) new connection was made
DEBUG connection_made ('127.0.0.1', 33974) new connection was made
DEBUG connection_made ('127.0.0.1', 33976) new connection was made
DEBUG data_received ('127.0.0.1', 33976) data received from new connection
DEBUG data_received ('127.0.0.1', 33974) data received from new connection
DEBUG data_received ('127.0.0.1', 33972) data received from new connection
```

I assume that its behaviour is analog to a stack where the data is received from the newest to the oldest connection made, but this is only a guess.

Is it possible to change that behaviour in a way that the data is received in the order that the connections were made? This is important because I need the data received from the first connection for further processing the following connections.

My code is the following:

```
import asyncio

class AIO(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extra = bytearray()

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        global request_time
        peer = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        logger.debug('{} new connection was made'.format(peer))
        self.transport = transport
        request_time = str(time.time())

    def data_received(self, request, msgid=1):
        peer = self.transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        logger.debug('{} data received from new connection'.format(peer))
        self.extra.extend(request)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the behavior here is stack-like, it could just be consequence of some implementation detail in asyncio or in the kernel. More importantly, even if asyncio guaranteed preserving the order, how can you be sure that data will be received at precisely the same time when the connection is established? In general, there is no guarantee that the connection that was established first will be the one to get some data first. Why is the order important to you? Perhaps you can change your architecture so that the precise order doesn't matter.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer. I'm not sure that the data is received at precisely the same time, but the connections are opened at the exact same time or at least directly after each other.

The order is important because I need the data send in the first connection for further processing of the data in the second connection.

Comment: I posted an answer that (I think) does what you you want, but I'm not convinced that it makes sense. The order in which your server observes connections "opened at the exact same time" could be completely random, depending on the details of the kernel or the network stack or even asyncio implementation details. If you need your connections to be ordered, you'll probably need to provide order at the client side.

Comment: I agree, then probably the client side doesn't make all connections at the same time but directly after each other and I understood this wrong. But the order of connections made and data received appears to be the same through further testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using the higher-level streams API instead of the transport/protocols. Then if you need to maintain the order observed when connections were made, you can enforce it yourself using a series of `asyncio.Event`s. For example:

```
import asyncio, itertools

class Comm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.extra = bytearray()
        self.preceding_evt = None

    async def serve(self, r, w):
        preceding_evt = self.preceding_evt
        self.preceding_evt = this_evt = asyncio.Event()
        while True:
            request = await r.read(4096)
            # wait for the preceding connection to receive and store data
            # before we store ours
            if preceding_evt is not None:
                await preceding_evt.wait()
                preceding_evt.clear()
            # self.extra now contains data from previous connections
            self.extra.extend(request)
            # inform the subsequent connection that we got data
            this_evt.set()
        w.close()

async def main():
    comm = Comm()
    server = await asyncio.start_server(comm.serve, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What does Comm() return? And how can I include functionality that I did within eof_received before, in the higher-level streams API/in this solution?

Comment: @Daniel Since `Comm` is a class, `Comm()` returns its instance. The instance created in `main()` will be shared among all the connections, just like your `AIO` class in the code in the question. The equivalent of `eof_received()` is reading an empty bytes object from `r.read()`.

Comment: @Daniel Also, note that `r.read(4096)` will read as much data as provided by the kernel, but no more than 4096 bytes. There is no guarantee that one whole request will be read in one read, so you might want to take steps to ensure that the whole response was read. (The approach will depend on what the request looks like.)

Comment: But why would you want to read the request in steps? Couldn't the whole response be read with `r.read()`?

Comment: @Daniel `r.read()` will return all data sent by the peer until they've closed their side of the socket, i.e. until end-of-file. The consequence is that after `r.read()` nothing else can be read, so it doesn't allow the peer to continue communicating with you over the same connection. If that works for you, great, and you get to eliminate the `while` loop as well. If not, you have to design a way to detect where your request ends. Another downside of `r.read()` is that an untrusted peer can DOS you by feeding you with infinite data which will cause your server to run out of memory.